# WordPress get or set active menu class

Tags: menus

How to get active menu class in wordpress, I want to get it in one plugin to change menu style.

Just to clear, I do not want active menu element class.

```
<ul id="menu-scroll" class="nav-menu">
<li id="menu-item-1461" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1461"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1462" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1462"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1463" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1463"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1466" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1466"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1468" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1468"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1467" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1467"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this I want to get "nav-menu" or i want to set new class like

```
<ul id="menu-scroll" class="my-nav-menu">
```

But not using themes file, I want to work it for all theme which is active.

Thanks In Advance,
Ajay

Comment: You can change it using js, just remove old class and replace it with your new class.

Comment: But how I know old class for different theme ?

Comment: There are standard class names for it http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes but themes can modify it.

Comment: That is the question, I want active theme active menu get,  set class/id.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easily done with a filter.

```
function alter_menu_class_wpse_113022($args) {
  // var_dump($args); // debug
  $args['menu_class'] = 'my-nav-menu';
  return $args;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args','alter_menu_class_wpse_113022');
```

That will make this line:

```
<ul id="menu-scroll" class="nav-menu">
```

Look like this one:

```
<ul id="menu-scroll" class="my-nav-menu">
```

But that could cause themes to break horribly. If a theme has used that class to apply styles to the menu, which would be a reasonable thing to do, you've just broken all of that styling. The effected menus will look terrible and may not even function. ***This is a very, very bad idea***. Please don't do it.

Comment: This code changes class of menu wrapper and not the class of ul tag.

Comment: What If I want to set new class ?

Comment: No. It doesn't. It changes the class of the `ul` tag.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I have checked it on twentythirteen theme and it's not adding class to ul instead it's adding class to ul wrapper div.

Comment: @VinodDalvi : I am looking at twentythirteen and it is inf fact changing the class on the `ul` and not the class on the surrounding `div`. I have no idea what you are looking at but I can alter that `ul` class very consistently by toggling that filter.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I don't know why it is happening at my side but therefore i have provided solution for it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the following safer way to add class to nav menu wrapper as it will not overwrite existing class.

```
function append_new_menu_class($args) {
  $args['menu_class'] = $args['menu_class'].' my-nav-menu';
  return $args;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args','append_new_menu_class');
```

The following code adds custom class to nav menu ul tag

```
function add_menuclass( $ulclass ) {
  return preg_replace( '/<ul>/', '<ul class="custom-class">', $ulclass, 1 );
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu', 'add_menuclass' );
```

Comment: I have added it on plugin file even in theme file but not adding, :l ?

Comment: Yes, but that is not what the OP is asking for and it is a trivial edit to my answer anyway.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I have added code for adding class to nav menu wrapper and also to nav menu ul.